# Multiple dex files define in Google Play Services

Tags: android, cordova, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

I am having the following dependencies in the build.gradle file. Note that I am using Ionic/Cordova mobile app.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
    debugCompile project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "debug")
    releaseCompile project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "release")
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:+"
    compile "com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.3.0@aar"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:+"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:+"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4+"
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
}
```

I get the below error during the build process.

```
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Dex: Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzah;
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzah;
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:591)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:546)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:528)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:164)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:504)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

I read the below SO links. It says about app level and module level gradle files. I am not sure which 2 files are those.

[Version conflict updating to 8.4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34370603/version-conflict-updating-to-8-4-0)

[Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzim;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37669490/multiple-dex-files-define-lcom-google-android-gms-internal-zzim)

[Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzau](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31224276/multiple-dex-files-define-lcom-google-android-gms-internal-zzau)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about the reason, but adding Google Admob library plugin the build was successful.

NOTE: I am using cordova plugin for Admob.

Answer (score 0):

That error occurs when you have the same library/directory included more than once in your build.gradle's dependencies. This looks also to be conflict with another plugin your using as stated in this [thread](https://github.com/geektimecoil/react-native-onesignal/issues/20).

You can check these links:

- [UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32798816/unexpected-top-level-exception-com-android-dex-dexexception-multiple-dex-files)

> Check all your dependencies in your build.gradle file. Are you referencing a dependency that also includes a dependency you have already included? For example, if your including appcompat-v7 there is no need to include appcompat-v4 since v7 includes all features from v4.

- [DexException: Multiple dex files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28335193/dexexception-multiple-dex-files)

> This error is caused by having too many method referenced in your project. [You can read more here.](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html) Generally it means that you need to remove unused libraries or use `proguard` even on debug build to reduce the number of method referenced. You may also go with the multi-dex approached mentioned in the article but it makes your project more complicated.